# extrema in multivariate functions under consrtraints

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Given that

$f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x,y) = e^{-xy}$
with constraint $x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$,

get the extrema of the function $f$

What I have tried so far:

I have set the latter equation as $y =\pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$

and substituted it into the function $f$, in order to get the first and the second derivates  with just one variable x. But this turned out to be awfully hectic, as I had to find in total of 4 derivatives and was wondering if there is a more elegant and concise way to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can make the calculations a bit simpler if you realize that the minima/maxima of an exponential will occur in the same points as the minima/maxima of the exponent.

So, in this case, it is possible to show the the global extrema are attained in critical points of the Lagrangian
$$
L(x,y,\lambda)= -xy -\lambda(x^2+y^2-1)
$$

These critical points turn out to be $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ and $(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$, and the global minimum/maximum are $e^{-1/2}$ and $e^{1/2}$, respectively.

Comment: We haven't gotten to the topic of Larange multiplier, so I had to look it up. As far as I understand the first term in the right hand side should be $e^{-xy}$ but since the minima/maxima of the term will occure in the same points as the minima/maxima of the exponent, it can be replaced with just $-xy$?

Comment: Yes, you can right from the start replace $f(x,y)=e^{-xy}$ by $\tilde f(x,y)=-xy$ and the minima/maxima occur at the same points.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use polar coordinates $x=\cos\theta, y=\sin \theta$ to simplify the optimization problem.

You are left with extremizing
$f(\theta)=\exp \left[ -\frac12 \sin(2\theta) \right]$

It is simple to find that
minima is reached when $\theta=\{-3\pi/4,\pi/4\}$ and
maxima at $\theta=\{-\pi/4,3\pi/4\}$.